# make: *** [Makefile:39: obj/main.o] Error 1

Tags: makefile

```
$ make
```

I was trying to complie in ubuntu and the result is following code.

```
find . -name "*.sh" -exec chmod +x {} \;
chmod: changing permissions of './bin/tiny-yolo-aix2022-int8-test.sh': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of './bin/tiny-yolo-aix2022.sh': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of './bin/tiny-yolo-aix2022-int8.sh': Operation not permitted
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create obj/main.o: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:39: obj/main.o] Error 1
```

Please help me... How can I solve this error?

Comment: Don't drip feed info. Reduce your makefile to the minimum to produce the error, then post it. At the moment all we can tell is that you do not have permissions to chmod files in the bin directory.

Comment: I would say, you should fix the permissions on your `obj` and `bin` directories.  That's about all we can say, with this information.